# Conversion between Cartesian vs. Polar Coordinates. Hoping the result is positive

Tags: python, numpy

I have several points that I need to covert them from Cartesian to Polar Coordinates. But for some points, the results I got were negative values.

For example, the origin or the center of the system is (50,50), and the point I want to covert is (10, 43). The angle I got from my code is -170.07375449, but I wish the angle is 189.92624551. (I hope all of the angles after conversion are between 0~360 degree)

How I fix this?

Thanks!!!

```
import numpy as np
points = np.array([(10, 43), (10, 44), (10, 45), (10, 46), (10, 47)])
#Set the center (origin) at (50, 50). Not (0, 0)
def cart_to_pol(coords, center = [50,50], deg = True):
    complex_format = np.array(coords, dtype = float).view(dtype = np.complex) -\
                     np.array(center, dtype = float).view(dtype = np.complex)
    # return np.abs(complex_format).squeeze(), np.angle(complex_format, deg = deg).squeeze()
    return np.angle(complex_format, deg=deg).squeeze()

print(cart_to_pol(points))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `np.where` to add 360 to the negative angles:

```
import numpy as np
points = np.array([(10, 43), (10, 44), (10, 45), (10, 46), (10, 47)])
#Set the center (origin) at (50, 50). Not (0, 0)
def cart_to_pol(coords, center = [50,50], deg = True):
    complex_format = np.array(coords, dtype = float).view(dtype = np.complex) -\
                     np.array(center, dtype = float).view(dtype = np.complex)
    angles = np.angle(complex_format, deg=deg).squeeze()
    summand = 360 if deg else 2*np.pi
    return np.where(angles < 0, angles+summand, angles)

print(cart_to_pol(points))
```

Output:

```
[189.92624551 188.53076561 187.12501635 185.71059314 184.28915333]
```

Note that complex numbers are not needed here. `arctan2(y, x)` calculates the desired angle. To get the distances: `np.linalg.norm(diff_with_center, axis=-1)`.

```py
def cart_to_pol(coords, center=[50, 50], deg=True):
    conversion = 180 / np.pi if deg else 1
    diff_with_center = points - center
    angles = np.arctan2(diff_with_center[:, 1], diff_with_center[:, 0])
    return conversion * np.where(angles < 0, angles + 2*np.pi, angles)
```

Answer (score 1):

If you need to convert [-180; 180] angle to [0; 360] you can use this code:

```
def convert_angle(angle):
    return (angle + 360) % 360
```

Answer (score 1):

Combining some of the other solutions here...

If you specify the origin and/or points as float, you can us a view to operate on them as complex numbers, and then simply return the angle modulo 360 degrees:

```
points = points - origin    
np.angle(points.view(np.complex), deg=True) % 360
>>> array([[189.92624551],
           [188.53076561],
           [187.12501635],
           [185.71059314],
           [184.28915333]])
```

Or, with in-place operations, assuming that points is already floating point:

```
np.subtract(points, origin, out=points)
v = points.view(np.complex)
np.arctan2(v.imag, v.real, out=v.real)
np.degrees(v.real, out=v.real)
np.mod(v.real, 360, out=v.real)
print(points[0])  # or print(v.real)
>>> array([[189.92624551],
           [188.53076561],
           [187.12501635],
           [185.71059314],
           [184.28915333]])
```

In this case we can't use `angle` because there is no `out` option, but we can compute arctan2 in-place in points[0], via our view. This uses no more memory than the original (floating point) points array, and while I didn't time it, should not take more operations to compute.